# double select in SQL query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Writing a code with two select statements in big query. Not sure why its not recognizing the fields. Getting error `Field --> 'd3.fiscal_week_begin_date'` not found; did you mean `'fiscal_week_begin_date'`?

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  [acquisition.acquisition_program_cost_summary] as test,
  (
  SELECT
    d.fiscal_week_begin_date AS fiscal_week_begin_date,
    d.fiscal_week_end_date AS fiscal_week_end_date
  FROM
    datamart.date_dim as d
  WHERE
    d.week_of_fiscal_year =30) as d3
WHERE
  test.created_timestamp >= d3.fiscal_week_begin_date
  AND test.created_timestamp <= d3.fiscal_week_end_date;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In BigQuery comma (,) does not represent JOIN but rather UNION ALL
So, most likely you meant to do JOIN like below
Please note you should switch to [BigQuery Standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/enabling-standard-sql)

```
SELECT *
FROM acquisition.acquisition_program_cost_summary as test
JOIN (
  SELECT
    d.fiscal_week_begin_date AS fiscal_week_begin_date,
    d.fiscal_week_end_date AS fiscal_week_end_date
  FROM datamart.date_dim as d
  WHERE d.week_of_fiscal_year = 30
) as d3
ON test.created_timestamp >= d3.fiscal_week_begin_date
AND test.created_timestamp <= d3.fiscal_week_end_date
```

Comment: Thanks Mikhail.  I agree with you and have tried the code but it gives error.

Comment: ON clause must be AND of = comparisons of one field name from each table, with all field names prefixed with table name.  here is the error

Comment: you should switch to Standard SQL! are you running/testing it in Web UI? see link in my answer

Comment: Yes it works with #standardSQL. Although i am not sure why we need that switch.

Comment: because by default it will run in Legacy Mode

Comment: I wrote the same query with one small addition #standardSQL
SELECT *
FROM acquisition.acquisition_program_cost_summary as test
JOIN (
  SELECT
    d.fiscal_week_begin_date AS fiscal_week_begin_date,
    d.fiscal_week_end_date AS fiscal_week_end_date,
    d.year
  FROM datamart.date_dim as d
  WHERE d.week_of_fiscal_year = 30
  and d.year = string((year(current_date())))
) as d3
ON test.created_timestamp>=d3.fiscal_week_begin_date
and test.created_timestamp<=d3.fiscal_week_end_date;
Its not able to recognize the year function

Comment: it is hard to answer new question within comments - I recommend you to ask/post new question so I (or someone else) will be able to answer it - this is usually the way it works on SO :o)